# Error instantiating an interface

Tags: blackberry

The following code fails to compile with message: `cannot instantiate type SymmetricKey` SymmetricKey is
 an interface.  How do I fix this?

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
 InitializationVector iv = new InitializationVector("helo".getBytes());
 SymmetricKey key = new SymmetricKey("AES_256","key", 0, "key".length());
 OutputStream os = EncryptorFactory.getEncryptorOutputStream(key, baos, "AES/CBC/PKCS5",);
 os.write("somedata".getBytes());
 byte[] encryptedData = baos.toByteArray();
 ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(encryptedData);
 InputStream is = DecryptorFactory.getDecryptorInputStream(key, bais, "AES/CBC/PKCS5", iv);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by using SymmetricKeyFactory

```
SymmetricKey key=
    SymmetricKeyFactory.getInstance("AES_256","key".getBytes(), 0, "abc123".length());
```